# SingleChildScrollView and NotificationListener

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to know how can I use SingleChildScrollView and NotificationListener together to create an infinite scroll.

Currently, I have this, but I don't see the print(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels) and print(scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) :

```
SliverList(
    delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
                print(scrollInfo.metrics.pixels);
                print(scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent);
                if (!_isLoading && scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
                    scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {

                    _addPost(context);

                    setState(() {
                        _isLoading = true;
                    });
                }
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: posts.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final Post post = posts[index];

                return PostContainer(post: post);
            }
        ),
        ),
    )
    ]),
),
```

Comment: What is the point of wrapping the ``ListView`` with  ``SingleChildScrollView`` in the first place when ``ListView`` can serve your purpose?

Comment: Also, ``SliverList`` used seems useless or serves no purpose!

Comment: @OMiShah I would like to use ListView with SliverList, because I use a custom SliverAppBar